# Zero cost builder pattern for recursive data structure using transmute. Is this safe? Is there a better approach?

Tags: rust, builder, unsafe, recursive-datastructures

I would like to create a `struct` using the builder pattern which must be validated before construction, and I would like to minimize the construction overhead.

I've come up with a nice way to do that using `std::mem::transmute`, but I'm far from confident that this approach is really safe, or that it's the best approach.

Here's my code: ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd4eaf9d816ff4a568e9e5d2e7af6a92))

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ValidStruct {
    items: Vec<ValidStruct>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Builder {
    pub items: Vec<Builder>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct InvalidStructError {}

impl Builder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { items: vec![] }
    }
    
    pub fn is_valid(&self) -> bool {
        self.items.len() % 2 == 1
    }
    
    pub fn build(self) -> Result<ValidStruct, InvalidStructError> {
        if !self.is_valid() {
            return Err(InvalidStructError {});
        }
        unsafe {
            Ok(std::mem::transmute::<Builder, ValidStruct>(self))
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut builder = Builder::new();
    builder.items.push(Builder::new());
    let my_struct = builder.build().unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", my_struct)
}
```

So, this seems to work. I think it should be safe because I know the two structs are identical. Am I missing anything? Could this actually cause problems somehow, or is there a cleaner/better approach available?

Comment: The structs are identical in your code but the order of the fields my be different after compilation (assuming there's more in the real use case). What is your goal here ? Do a faster build ? Then this kind of optimization is best left to the compiler.

Comment: @DenysSéguret - I could use `#[repr(C)]` to avoid the field order issue right? I would love to leave the optimization to the compiler. But if I'm going in and recursively converting every `item` I'm pretty sure the compiler won't do the optimization I want. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your idea here is that the builder has the same fields, but public, and that the ValidStruct is the same but checked ? Why not wrap the temporary object instead (wrapping is costless) ? The ValidStruct could thus be `struct ValidStruct { data: Data }` with Data having public fields and being the builder.

Comment: Ohh - and the goal is to avoid O(n) runtime performance running `build`. In principle, it should be O(1), but if I have to descend recursively into the items it won't be.

Comment: How are you going to avoid descent when validating ? Do you just want to validate the top level ?

Comment: You're right. The validation will have to be recursive anyway. I think your wrapper approach is exactly what I want. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't normally transmute between different structures just because they seem to have the same fields in the same order, because the compiler might change that. You can avoid the risk by forcing the memory layout but you're then fighting the compiler and preventing optimizations. This approach isn't usually recommended and is, in my opinion, not needed here.

What you want is to have

- a recursive data structure with public fields so that you can easily build it
- an identical structure, built from the first one but with no public access and only built after validation of the first one

And you want to avoid useless copies for performance reasons.

What I suggest is to have a wrapper class. This makes sense because wrapping a struct in another one is totally costless in Rust.

You could thus have

```
/// This is the "Builder" struct
pub struct Data {
    pub items: Vec<Data>,
}
pub struct ValidStruct {
    data: Data, // no public access here
}
impl Data {
    pub fn build(self) -> Result<ValidStruct, InvalidStructError> {
        if !self.is_valid() {
            return Err(InvalidStructError {});
        }
        Ok(Self{ data })
    }
}
```

(alternatively, you could declare a struct `Builder` as a wrapper of `Data` too but with a public access to its field)